# How to make firebase GID Signin always ask for the useremail and password?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with firebase google login with gmail.

My intend: I want it to always ask for new username and password

My problem: every time I successfully logged out with

```
do {
            try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.currentUser = nil
        }catch let err  {
            print ("error signout - \(err)")
        }
```

when I press login button, it automatically logged in with the prev Gmail

Answer (score 1):

You have to log out your instance of GoogleSignIn as well:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
```

It's documented here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#sign_out_the_user